# python float to integer list mismatch

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, data-conversion

I'm writing some python code that needs to convert a real to an integer:

Section of the relevant code:

```
for q in range(len(diff2FittedFunc[:])):
    moveBack=(10.0/len(diff2FittedFunc[:]))*q
    rampPosition = 10-moveBack 
    arrayPos=int(rampPosition*10)
    print rampPosition,arrayPos
```

I expected (and wanted) the list that is printed to output a list of values from 100 to 1 in increments of 1. After checking the list, I noticed that there are missing values and duplicate values e.g. 38.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening and how I can correct it?

(FYI: `len(diff2FittedFunc[:] = 100`)

Thank you very much in advance.

**OUTPUT:**

```
- 10.0 100
- 9.9 99
- 9.8 98
- 9.7 97
- 9.6 96
- 9.5 95
- 9.4 94
- 9.3 93
- 9.2 92
- 9.1 91
- 9.0 90
- 8.9 89
- 8.8 88
- 8.7 87
- 8.6 86
- 8.5 85
- 8.4 84
- 8.3 83
- 8.2 82
- 8.1 81
- 8.0 80
- 7.9 79
- 7.8 78
- 7.7 77
- 7.6 76
- 7.5 75
- 7.4 74
- 7.3 73
- 7.2 72
- 7.1 71
- 7.0 70
- 6.9 69
- 6.8 68
- 6.7 67
- 6.6 66
- 6.5 65
- 6.4 64
- 6.3 63
- 6.2 61
- 6.1 61
- 6.0 60
- 5.9 58
- 5.8 58
- 5.7 57
- 5.6 56
- 5.5 55
- 5.4 53
- 5.3 53
- 5.2 51
- 5.1 51
- 5.0 50
- 4.9 48
- 4.8 48
- 4.7 46
- 4.6 46
- 4.5 45
- 4.4 43
- 4.3 43
- 4.2 41
- 4.1 41
- 4.0 40
- 3.9 38
- 3.8 38
- 3.7 36
- 3.6 36
- 3.5 35
- 3.4 33
- 3.3 33
- 3.2 31
- 3.1 30
- 3.0 30
- 2.9 28
- 2.8 28
- 2.7 26
- 2.6 25
- 2.5 25
- 2.4 23
- 2.3 23
- 2.2 21
- 2.1 20
- 2.0 20
- 1.9 19
- 1.8 17
- 1.7 16
- 1.6 15
- 1.5 15
- 1.4 14
- 1.3 12
- 1.2 11
- 1.1 10
- 1.0 10
- 0.9 9
- 0.8 7
- 0.7 6
- 0.6 5
- 0.5 5
- 0.4 3
- 0.3 2
- 0.2 1
- 0.1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's rounding the floats up but truncating the integers. Try this and it should show you the problem:

Try changing the last line to

`print "{:.2f}".format(rampPosition),arrayPos`

Comment: I wasn't able to determine the solution to this problem by applying your line.

Comment: OK. Can you append the output you get when you run it with the line changed?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing such a task using string. I see the function as just removing the decimal.
Here is my version of the function:

```
def func(real):
    temp=str(real)
    temp=list(temp)
    temp.remove(".")
    temp="".join(temp)
    return int(temp)
```